# Right Bottom Feedback button

Tags: html, css

I try to set this image -

[image]

as right bottom located "Feedback" button .

I located it at the right bottom location with -

```
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 92%;
```

**[Here its jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/RdrZe/)**

but I don't get the desire display (I get just a border with no image within) .

How to fix it ?

**Update:**

I want it displayed in the right bottom with the image too .

Comment: Why does to downvote ? What is not clarify or wrong here ?

Comment: Your JSfiddle is very sloppy which is probably why you were downvoted. The image doesn't appear, and you're putting all of the styles into an arbitrary media query.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/RdrZe/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position it correctly.

If you want it to be positioned in the **Bottom Right**, you need to do that instead of trying to position from some crazy abstract from the top.

```
#feedback_button {
    height: 67px;
    width: 67px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/RdrZe/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You must define a `width` and `height` when you're using background images and no inner content.. like this:

```
  #feedback_button {
    background: url("http://air-staging-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/feedback_icon.png") 0 0 no-repeat transparent;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width:67px;
    height:67px;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ChubbyNinja/RdrZe/4/